# Firefox + firebug, prototype + jquery.noconflict : Firefox crashes on page load

Tags: jquery, firefox, crash, firebug, prototype

I am in the process to move from `Prototype` to `jQuery`.

As a first step, I am using both libraries, using `$j=jQuery.noConflict()`;

It works well in all browsers I have tried so far, but if I open Firebug, Firefox crashes when the page load.

Did you hear about similar problems ? How can I check what goes on with Firebug ?

Comment: Is there an incident link in your about:crashes for this crash?

Comment: Well the problem is solved by updateing to Firefox 17.01 (I tried a last time before updating, and I had the crash, but now it's working). For my knowledge, where ist this about:crash ? (I could only see the crash report sent to the Mozilla team, but there was no information I could use on it).

Comment: If you just type `about:crashes` in the Firefox URL bar, it'll give you a list of the crash reports you've sent in, with links to analyzed versions of the crash reports which have things like callstacks and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by updating to Firefox 17.0.1.
As the problem was reproductible, I guess it was a bug somewhere... But has been corrected somehow.